# How to single out specific points on bell curve like data

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to develop a code in which, when a certain temperature is reached, the time that temperature occurred at is outputted. I was given the temperature outputs and the time that corresponds with each, but the temperature I am looking for happens at various points in the data and I'm not sure how to implement code that picks up when each of these happen and then spits out the time relative to it. For example, my data looks like...

`Time                  Temp
10/2/2019 8:20:50      78.8
10/2/2019 8:21:00      79
10/2/2019 8:21:10      79
10/2/2019 8:21:20      79
10/2/2019 8:21:30      79`

And I need to find what time it was every time the temperature hits 200 and some arbitrary temperature value that I have been calling tmin

Im fairly new to python. So far I just have a for loop that can determine when the temperature is in between certain temperatures.

```
    if i<200:
        print('Less than 200')
    elif 200<= i <=xmin:
        print('Between 200 and tmin')
    else:
        print('Above tmin')
```

Where CH1 is the column of temperatures

I'm just not sure how to a)show the time that occurs once the temperature occurrence is identified, and b)to determine every instance of the temperature value occurring and any ideas/help would be appreciated.

Comment: We need additional information to answer this. How is your data formatted? in a CSV? how are you reading it? Is it stored in an array? a dictionary?

Comment: The data is currently formatted from a CSV file and then once imported, I used the to_datetime and to_numeric functions to convert them from reading as str.